# Finding constraints on right-hand side to yield feasible constrained linear problem

Tags: linear-algebra, constraint-programming

I have the following constrained linear system:

$$
Ax = y \\
Cx \ge b
$$

where
$$
y\in \mathbb{R}^3 \\
x \in \mathbb{R}^n \\
b \in \mathbb{R}^m \\
$$
Also, $n$ and $m$ are typically greater than 3, e.g. say 4 and 10 respectively.

For my specific application, the inequality constraints are always such that they create a convex polygon, in case that is of any use.

Is it possible to find a set of linear constraints on $y$, i.e.
$$
Dy \ge g
$$
such that the original system has solutions?

Algebraic solutions are preferred, but numerical solutions are also of interest.

Answer (score 0):

So I spent some time on the problem and arrived at the following:

Assuming the 3 rows of $A$ are not linearly dependent, we can first partition the unknowns $x$ into subsets $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$, where $k=n-3$. This leads to a corresponding partitioning of the matrices:

$$
Ax =
\begin{pmatrix}
A_1 & A_2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{pmatrix} = y\\
Cx =
\begin{pmatrix}
C_1 & C_2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{pmatrix} \ge b\\
$$
Furthermore, we can introduce the auxiliary variables $\lambda = x_2$, by augmenting the equality system with $k$ additional equalities, yielding
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A_1 & A_2\\
0 & \mathbb{I}_{k \times k}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
y\\
\lambda
\end{pmatrix} .
$$
Now, the block matrix can be inverted yielding
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
A_1^{-1} & -A_1^{-1}A_2\\
0 & \mathbb{I}_{k \times k}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y\\
\lambda
\end{pmatrix} .
$$
This can now be plugged into the system of inequalities,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
C_1 & C_2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
C_1 & C_2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
A_1^{-1} & -A_1^{-1}A_2\\
0 & \mathbb{I}_{k \times k}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y\\
\lambda
\end{pmatrix} \ge b.
$$
Simplifying, we get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
C_1 A_1^{-1} & C_2 -C_1 A_1^{-1}A_2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y\\
\lambda
\end{pmatrix} \ge b\\
C_1 A_1^{-1}y +(C_2 -C_1 A_1^{-1}A_2)\lambda \ge b
$$
or
$$
C_1 A_1^{-1}y \ge b + (C_1 A_1^{-1}A_2 - C_2)\lambda \, .
$$
These are now the sought inequalities for $y$ for which there are solutions to the original problem. However, we now have the parameters $\lambda$ left, which are allowed to take on any value as long as all the inequalities hold simultaneously for a given $y$. In other words, $y$ is a solution if there exists a $\lambda$ for which the inequalities hold.

I'm convinced it should be possible to get rid of the parametrization and just have fixed inequalities, but I haven't gotten anywhere with that yet.  Any help with solving that part would be greatly appreciated.